# How to fix unknown field 'suspend' specified in initializer when compiling smartass governor?

Tags: android, c++, c, kernel

I have been trying to figure out why when i try to compile my android kernel it gives me this error for smarts governor:

```
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_smartass2.c:844:2: error: unknown field 'suspend' specified in initializer
      .suspend = smartass_early_suspend,
      ^
    drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_smartass2.c:844:13: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
    error, forbidden warning: cpufreq_smartass2.c:844
    make[2]: *** [drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_smartass2.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [drivers/cpufreq] Error 2
    make: *** [drivers] Error 2
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I checked the line that was giving me error and it was an initialisation of variable which is a member of a struct data structure. The code is below:

```
static struct early_suspend smartass_power_suspend = {
        .suspend = smartass_early_suspend,
        .resume = smartass_late_resume,
    #ifdef CONFIG_MACH_HERO
        .level = EARLY_SUSPEND_LEVEL_DISABLE_FB + 1,
    #endif
    };
```

Below is the full code:

```
static void smartass_suspend(int cpu, int suspend)
{
    struct smartass_info_s *this_smartass = &per_cpu(smartass_info, smp_processor_id());
    struct cpufreq_policy *policy = this_smartass->cur_policy;
    unsigned int new_freq;

    if (!this_smartass->enable)
        return;

    smartass_update_min_max(this_smartass,policy,suspend);
    if (!suspend) { // resume at max speed:
        new_freq = validate_freq(policy,sleep_wakeup_freq);

        dprintk(SMARTASS_DEBUG_JUMPS,"SmartassS: awaking at %d\n",new_freq);
        __cpufreq_driver_target(policy, new_freq,
                    CPUFREQ_RELATION_L);
    } else {
        // to avoid wakeup issues with quick sleep/wakeup don't change actual frequency when entering sleep
        // to allow some time to settle down. Instead we just reset our statistics (and reset the timer).
        // Eventually, the timer will adjust the frequency if necessary.

        this_smartass->freq_change_time_in_idle =
            get_cpu_idle_time_us(cpu,&this_smartass->freq_change_time);

        dprintk(SMARTASS_DEBUG_JUMPS,"SmartassS: suspending at %d\n",policy->cur);
    }

    reset_timer(smp_processor_id(),this_smartass);
}

static void smartass_early_suspend(struct early_suspend *handler) {
    int i;
    if (suspended || sleep_ideal_freq==0) // disable behavior for sleep_ideal_freq==0
        return;
    suspended = 1;
    for_each_online_cpu(i)
        smartass_suspend(i,1);
}

static void smartass_late_resume(struct early_suspend *handler) {
    int i;
    if (!suspended) // already not suspended so nothing to do
        return;
    suspended = 0;
    for_each_online_cpu(i)
        smartass_suspend(i,0);
}

static struct early_suspend smartass_power_suspend = {
    .suspend = smartass_early_suspend,
    .resume = smartass_late_resume,
#ifdef CONFIG_MACH_HERO
    .level = EARLY_SUSPEND_LEVEL_DISABLE_FB + 1,
#endif
};
```

The code seems syntactically correct, I have hit a brick wall with this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `struct early_suspend`? The error message says that this structure doesn't have a member named `suspend`.

Comment: Found it: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/a7827a2a60218b25f222b54f77ed38f57aebe08b/include/linux/earlysuspend.h what is the value of `CONFIG_HAS_EARLYSUSPEND`?

Comment: I looked around it isn't initialised with a value. It's set as #define i.e defined(CONFIG_HAS_EARLYSUSPEND)

Comment: It *is* defined? Are you sure? It looks like a kernel config option, is it set in your config? Add `#ifndef CONFIG_HAS_EARLYSUSPEND #error "oops" #endif` with each `#` on a new line somewhere into that file and compile again.

Comment: I look through my git using the search function for initialization for CONFIG_HAS_EARLYSUSPEND didn't see anything like that.

Comment: @NickSpirit, this option is *for setting by user* when kernel is configured (e.g. with `make menuconfig`). For check, whether option is set in your current configuration, use `grep HAS_EARLYSUSPEND .config` (from kernel's source directory).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried that command but it didn't do anything or showed me some output, isn't it suppose to show me something.

Comment: Empty output means that option is not set in your current configuration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I found how to add EARLYSUSPEND to the menuconfig and now i don't get that error message any longer. But now I get another error message and i can't figure out why. The necessary information is above

Comment: Function `register_early_suspend` is defined in `kernel/power/earlysuspend.c`, but this file is never used for compile kernel (`kernel/power/Makefile` should issue it, but it doesn't). According to commit dates and messages, `early_suspend` mechanism is currently under development, so it can have non-working things now.

Comment: @Tsyvarev are you on fb or hangouts, need to ask you a few more questions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev I fixed the problem of the "unknown field 'suspend' specified in initializer"

After trying to add other governors and trying to compile I receive this error message for the new ones that I have added

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function cpufreq_smartass_init':
/home/nick/android/LGD722LKernel/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_smartass2.c:898: undefined reference to `register_early_suspend'
```

[Link to the complete code for cpufreq_smartass2.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheNotOnly/android_kernel_lge_jagnm_lp/master/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_smartass2.c)

[Link to the complete code for earlysuspend.h](https://github.com/TheNotOnly/android_kernel_lge_jagnm_lp/blob/master/include/linux/earlysuspend.h)

I have checked the function register_eary_suspend and the way it was called and the way the parameter was passed to the function looks correct. I think it may be from the makefile, but that's just my opinion. If anyone has any other ideas what the problem could be, please share I don't have much experience with kernel development and your ideas/suggestions will really help me.